# Form Helper Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to access the view, an error is returned: 
undefined method 'title' for #Task id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil

tasks_controller.rb (Controller)

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
def new
    @task = Task.new
end


    def create
        @task = Task.new(params[:task])
        if @task.save
        redirect_to new_task_path
        end
    end 
end
```

/tasks/new.html.erb (View)

```
<%= form_for :task, url: tasks_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :details %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :details %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

task.rb (Model)

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :title, :details, :user_id, :volunteers
end
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined fields in your database, see:

```
#Task id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil
```

There is no title nor details there, do this:

```
rails g migration add_title_and_details_to_tasks title details
```

Check that your migration file is correctly creating these 2 fields.

Then run `rake db:migrate`. Next time remember to generate your resource with these fields:

```
rails g scaffold Task title details
```

This way, when you migrate your fields will be there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have pending migration(s) (do you have `title` in your `schema.rb`).

other note: build your form for `@task`